# Enter the Password

Tags: cipher, password

You sit in front of a computer terminal. To save a puppy from beeing eaten by a unicorn (I'll make up a better background next time) you need to enter the correct password of 4 letters. You are given a hint:

```
4:6 2:1 3:0 3:0 3:3 3:7 3:2 3:4 : 4:8 4:4 3:1 1:0
P   A   S   S   W   O   R   D   :
```

What is the Password?

Clue:

> Neither my son nor my father could solve this, unless they worked together.

Comment: I must say, very insecure password ;)

Comment: @me_digvijay Unicorns are quite trusting I guess. :)

Comment: I presume the clue is that `4:6` equates to `P`, etc. That would mean the password we seek is four characters.

Comment: @EngineerToast: Confirmed.

Comment: I think I heard the clue somewhere else ... :/ I can't recall where

Comment: @lois6b: Would be coincidence, as I created this puzzle right for this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> BLUE

Reasoning

> The code is a mix between morse code and binary, so a number pair **A:B** tells you that the letter has **A** characters in its morse code representation and if we translate that representation to binary (with dashes as 1s and dots as 0s), we get **B**.

Example

> The first number is 4:6, this means we have four morse code characters which in binary represents 6, i.e, 0110 = .--. = P. 
>  The others are 
>  4:8 $\rightarrow$ 1000 $\rightarrow$ -... $\rightarrow$ B 
>  4:4 $\rightarrow$ 0100 $\rightarrow$ .-.. $\rightarrow$ L 
>  3:1 $\rightarrow$ 001 $\rightarrow$ ..- $\rightarrow$ U 
>  1:0  $\rightarrow$ 0 $\rightarrow$ . $\rightarrow$ E

Comment: and about the clue?

Comment: @lois6b morse code is something his father would know (fairly old technique). binary is something his son would know (fairly recent technique)

Comment: @nl-x could be ^^'

Comment: Looks like a great answer! Pity if there were really a typo in the question though, as its a pretty good puzzle too.

Comment: @Xenocacia, it seems its correct answer as the OP edited the question

Comment: Unfortunately the 0:0 was indeed a typo. Can't say how much this annoys me. :/

Comment: I was trying to figure out why the first number was even necessary and then I realized it was to tell you how many leading zeros you need.